# PowerShell 3.0 x64 bit broken after installing KB2506143

Tags: powershell

I have searched using all kinds of variations on relevant terms and I cannot find a single other instance of someone else having this excact same problem, so I am hoping someone here may have a clue.

## Problem

I installed Windows Management Framework 3.0 (KB2506143) by downloading and running Windows6.1-KB2506143-x64.msu from Microsoft.com. Once completed I rebooted my machine as requested.  After rebooting and logging in, I try to run the 64-bit PowerShell command shell and it comes up for a second then goes away. The 32-bit shell seems to work fine, it is just the 64-bit one that fails.

Looking in the Fusion logs, I found:

```
*** Assembly Binder Log Entry  (10/4/2012 @ 1:51:48 PM) ***

The operation failed.
Bind result: hr = 0x80070002. The system cannot find the file specified.

Assembly manager loaded from:  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\mscorwks.dll
Running under executable  C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
--- A detailed error log follows. 

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: User = ********\*****
LOG: DisplayName = Microsoft.PowerShell.ConsoleHost, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL
<remainder omitted>
```

GacUtil reveals that there is a Microsoft.PowerShell.ConsoleHost, Version=1.0.0.0, but not 3.0.0.0.

I tried uninstalling KB2506143 (which removed MSVCRT90.dll and caused Windows Live Messenger to fail on load after rebooting again, so I ran a repair in stall on Windows Live Essentials and that fixed the Messenger problem) and then re-installing it, but nothing changed.

If it helps, here are what I think may be the relevant parts of my hardware/software environment.

## Environment

- Dell Latitude E6510, 8GB RAM
- Windows 7 Professional 64-bit with SP1
- Visual Studio 2010 Professional installed (includes .NET 4.0)
- Visual Studio 2012 Professional installed
- Microsoft Forefront Client Security

Any clues out there?

Thanks,
Dave

Comment: Windows 7 I assume?

Comment: Did you ever have a beta version of PoSH 3 installed?

Comment: Did you attempt to re-install powershell 3?

Comment: a) Yes, Windows 7. Sorry I meant to make that part of the "Windows Professional" line. b) No, I never installed the beta. This was my first install. c) The only way (that I know of) to install PowerShell 3 is via Windows Management Framework 3.0 (KB2506143). As noted (although I see that I did not make it clear that the KB was the same thing as the installer above), I did try uninstalling and re-installing that.  No joy.

Comment: I edited the post to clarify Windows 7 and also tie the KB# with the package referenced in the first paragraph. 

@Craig620, thinking about it a little more, it is possible that I tried installed PowerShell 3.0 some months ago, but it would not install because at the time I did not have Windows 7 SP1 installed. So just to cover all bases, if I had installed the Beta, what would I have to do to clean up from there?  Also, I do have the Windows PowerShell 2.0 SDK installed, if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 2):

Which KB2506143 are you installing? When I google KB2506143, I get [this link](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29939) for download that is the "release candidate" for WMF3.0

When  I google "Windows Management Framework 3.0" I get a [different link](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=34595) that does NOT mention "release candidate".

The file sizes for Windows6.1-KB2506143-x64.msu listed on the two pages are different. If you're still running the RC try the final release.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get email notifications for this so I did not see your question until now. I installed the RTM version. It says nothing about RC, CTP, or anything else.

Comment: The installer does not mention RC or CTP. The page I posted for the KB you mention KB2506143 has the title "Windows Management Framework 3.0 - RC" http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29939. Do you still have the problem after installing the RTM?